# Where can I get a complete reference on Mac OS X's CoreWLAN?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, documentation

Googling for `CoreWLAN` brings a [mere 701 results](http://www.google.com/search?q=CoreWLan) -- Apple's own shallow [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/) isn't even there, at least not on the first pages.

For instance, I would like to know what are the possible values of `kCWScanKeyScanType` when scanning for networks. Apple will only say it defaults to `APScanTypeActive`, but doesn't explain what that means or what are the other possibilities. I obscurely came across a [QT commit](http://qt.gitorious.org/~beerlington/qt/beerlingtons-wkhtmltopdf-qt/commit/ee6483a76e62a69641530f36ad35f1f686914442) which uses `kCWScanTypeFast`, for which there are no Google results except for 3 commit logs.

It seems I'm missing something. Where can I get a full reference on CoreWLAN, if one exists? If it doesn't, how did Nokia discover `kCWScanTypeFast`?

Comment: Much of Apple's documentation has disappeared from Google because of Apple's new JavaScript-based documentation loader. Note the # in the URL in your link; everything before it is what Google considers to be the URL of *every page in the Apple documentation*. So, Google indexes all of those documentation links under one URL—it doesn't know that they're supposed to refer to different things. The old-style URLs that have survived in Google's index have dropped in PageRank because Apple no longer links to them. Thanks, Apple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the documentation is terse or there’s no documentation, resort to header files. In particular, /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework/Headers/CWGlobals.h declares the `CWScanType` enumeration with three possible values: `kCWScanTypeActive`, `kCWScanTypePassive`, and `kCWScanTypeFast`. The header file documents that `enum` and the respective values.